# Database Objects Scripts in Order?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When we script all Sql Server Database objects from Management Studio by right clicking on the database, and go to tasks and select "generate scripts", will the generated scripts be in order???

Comment: why don't you run it and find out.

Comment: Which *order* and what version of SSMS are you using?

Comment: @Mitch: That's *so* crazy, it might just work..

Comment: 'in order'? As in correctly structured so that when executed they create object/tables/users/etc in the correct sequence so as to recreate the scripted database? It'd be a bit crap if it didn't.

Comment: @Mitch: I think it will be in order if we script everything out rather than select the objects. But, my developer is not convinced. 
@astander: SSMS 2005

Comment: @Lazarus: Yes, thas what I have seen for few databases. I have not done it for a lot. That why I m not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking in terms of dependencies, I can confirm that it does work as you would expect. Objects that have dependencies are scripted after their dependents

Comment: I found recently something on Pinal Dev blog and some people were complaining about only views not scripted in right order.

Comment: In the past I’ve run into ordering problems when I scripted the table, views, ... separately (i.e. ran the script generator once for tables, and again for views, ...). However, when I script the objects in one process the ordering is fine.

Comment: @rip: When you script all at once and you found the order right, then I would assume that any of the table structures were never changed. If some of them were changed and you did not refresh the views, then when you script everything out, your order will not be right. So, one needs to refresh the views first before scripting out all objects and everything will be in order.